# Constant Tkinter window update

Tags: python, tkinter

As a first project I decided to build an app that will show me the current price of oil so I will not have to look at the Forex charts whole time.

The issue with this app is that the "update" loop only prints oil price every 3 seconds, so I know that this loop is executed constantly, but it not only does not update the text in window, but it also crashes it, while shell prints the price of oil.

I tried to use Multiprocessing module but it made no difference.

```
def window():
    root = Tk()
    screen_width  = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
    mylabel = Label( root, text = "" )
    mylabel.pack()

def update():
    while True:
        global string_price
        request = requests.get( "http://www.biznesradar.pl/notowania/BRENT-OIL-ROPA-BRENT#1d_lin_lin" )
        content = request.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup( content, "html.parser" )
        element = soup.find( "span", { "class": "q_ch_act" } )
        string_price = ( element.text.strip() )
        print( string_price )
        mylabel.configure( text = str( string_price ) )

        time.sleep( 3 )

root.after( 400, update )
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.after`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632/tkinter-how-to-use-after-method) method, already does what you wanted from `while True` and `sleep` at the same time. Remove both `sleep` and `while` and add another `after` inside to call continuously.

```
def custom_update():
    global string_price
    request = requests.get("http://www.biznesradar.pl/notowania/BRENT-OIL-ROPA-BRENT#1d_lin_lin")
    content = request.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
    element = soup.find("span", {"class": "q_ch_act"})
    string_price = (element.text.strip())
    print(string_price)
    mylabel.configure(text=str(string_price))
    root.after(3000, custom_update) #notice it calls itself after every 3 seconds

custom_update() #since you want to check right after opening no need to call after here as Bryan commented
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped a lot! I also changed the time value in the "root.after" at the very bottom of your code for "0" so the app checks the oil price right after opening.

Comment: You don't need to use `after` the first time you call it. You can directly call `update()`. However, you should probably name the function something else. All widgets have an `update` method, so having your own `update` method might be confusing.

Comment: @KarolMularski please check after edits as well. Some changes applied according to Bryan's suggestions.

Comment: This piece of code works just great! I also deleted "global string_price", which was used when I was trying to run this app with multiprocessing module, now it is not needed. 
Thanks for help, you guys are the best!